# Create a Connected App in Patch Org

Tags: managed-package, package, patch

I am trying to streamline our patch delivery process using first generation packages. I planned to write a CI/CD action to deploy changes to the patch org but I ran into an issue when creating a connected app.

I get the error "Consumers cannot be created in a patch organization".

I assume this is a hard limitation but was wondering if anyone has tried something similar and if you were able to find a work around.

Comment: Why are you creating a connected app? You can use one on your PBO against any org if you want to need to.

Comment: I am not familiar with how this work. I created a connected app and generated an access token, when trying to do `sf org login access-token` I get the error Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange. Due to: Bad_OAuth_Token. Any thoughts?

Comment: Feels like using the Salesforce CLI's login mechanism could be what you need?